# Dynamic Carousel Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I am getting an array from the backend, and I want to display it as a carousel using angular.

- The component must be responsive.
- Every slide will contain multiple items.

Any idea on how I can implement this?

Thanks

Comment: I suppose you mean the carousel component available here: http://angular-ui.github.com/bootstrap/#/carousel. Please try to be as specific as possible, and add references/links for people who might be unfamiliar with the library you are using!

Comment: [Ask], and first show us what you tried yourself.

Comment: can use any carousel system you want... pick one

Answer (score -1):

Jcarousel have resolve my problems :

```
<div class="jcarousel-skin-default">
    <div id="class1" class="jcarousel">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div ng-repeat="object in objects" id="ribbon-item">{{object.name}}</div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <a class="btn" href="#" onclick="$('#class1').jcarousel('scroll', '-=1'); return false;"><i class="icon-step-backward"></i></a>
    <a class="btn" href="#" onclick="$('#class1').jcarousel('scroll', '+=1'); return false;"><i class="icon-step-forward"></i></a>
</div>
```

and a JQUERY call :

```
    $('#class1').jcarousel();
```

resolve my pain.